# How to create custom modal segue in 4.2 Xcode using storyboard

Tags: ipad, sdk, ios5

I'm using storyboard to create my new iPad project. I want use the custom modal segue to have better transitions between views. My question is how do I use the custom modal and is there any tutorials out there that show using custom modal segues?

Answer (score 5):

This custom seque pops back to the root of a navigation stack. Use a normal pop instead of "popToViewController" if you want to go back one level. I just love the name of this method.

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FlipTopPopToRoot : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "FlipTopPopToRoot.h"

@implementation FlipTopPopToRoot

- (void) perform {

UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
[UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                animations:^{
                    [src.navigationController popToViewController:[src.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];;
                }
                completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar and found the current answer a bit misleading. The current tutorial presented by TJ is performing a customized segue within a navigation controller. If you are looking for a modal segue I believe you need to call instead:

```
 [self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
```

and change the options of your animation.

More can be found on this post I wrote: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466231/how-do-you-perform-a-customized-segue-modal-segue-from-a-button-in-storyboard).

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be the easiest method rather than writing mounds of code to just slide a frame.

Here's the custom segue

```
- (void) perform {
    UIView *oldView = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *newView = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

    [oldView.window insertSubview:newView aboveSubview:oldView];
    float offsetY = newView.center.y  - oldView.center.y ;
    //NSLog(@"old y = %f, new y = %f , offsetY = %f", oldView.center.y, newView.center.y, offsetY);


    // assuming newView and oldView both sized to fill screen,
    //   position newView just to the right of oldView

    newView.center = CGPointMake(oldView.center.x + oldView.frame.size.width, oldView.center.y + offsetY);
    //NSLog(@"newView center x = %f y = %f", newView.center.x, newView.center.y);
    // slide newView over oldView, then remove oldView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{ newView.center = CGPointMake(oldView.center.x, oldView.center.y + offsetY);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [oldView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have used code similar to this in a project I am making, how do you return to the original view that the new view replaces.