# UIView sliding transition fades

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, transition, catransition

I've got some code inside one of my view controllers that will make sliding transition from one view to another:

```
-(void)transitionToNewView:(UIView*)newView
{

    UIView *superView = [self.view superview]; 
    [superView addSubview:newView]; 
    newView.frame = superView.bounds;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation]; 
    [animation setDuration:0.5]; 
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft]; 
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[superView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"keygoeshere"];
}
```

The sliding transition seems to work correctly, but I'm also seeing the new view fade in from a blank screen in addition to the sliding. I suspect that this is because I'm adding a new view to the super view that wasn't there before. What I'd like to do is the same thing, but without the fading in. How can I do this?

Comment: Core animation defaults to a fade when an error occurs or an invalid parameter is passed to the animation object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the kCATransitionPush transition does a fade at the same time by design. I could swear I remember reading that somewhere.

It would be pretty simple to construct a view-to-view push transition using the method transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:.

Pass in UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone for the transition option, and then use an animation block that slides the current view off-screen while sliding the new view on-screen from the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a straight answer to your issue but one way I found out for handling transition between two views is to add the new view to your superview like you did, take a screenshot of each view, realize the animation and remove the two screenshots views when the transition is done. I explained more in detail what i did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466231/how-do-you-perform-a-customized-segue-modal-segue-from-a-uibutton-in-storyboar) and it works very well. I think it worth a try to resolve the problem you are facing. Any reason otherwise you don't use the animateWithDuration method on UIView?