# segue from landscape only to portrait only

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, orientation, segue

I have two "pages" in my app. one which should rotate between the 2 landscape modes but not allow portrait mode and the other which should rotate between the 2 portrait modes but not allow landscape mode.

How can one set this up so that the orientations are limited correctly when segueing between the two views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write my `own` segue if I were you and set the orientation of the destination view in the `perform` method of your custom `UIStoryboardSegue` and will also set the orientation i want to allow in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`of the destination view controller. You can have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466231/how-do-you-perform-a-customized-segue-modal-segue-from-a-uibutton-in-storyboar) related to custom segue I asked some time ago to get an idea of how to implement custom segue.

Comment: Perfect! I just made a custom segue to do a horizontal cover transition so im a little familiar with that process. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.