# Landscape Segue Between Two Portrait UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, uiinterfaceorientation

I am only allowing Device Orientation portrait for UIViewControllers being viewed on iPhones through the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSString *device = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    return [device rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound ? NO : YES;
}
```

This works fine - when I rotate my iPhone while looking at ViewController A, the view does not rotate. Similarly, when I rotate my iPhone while looking at ViewController B, the view does not rotate.  However, when I rotate my iPhone while looking at ViewController A, tap a button that presents ViewController B modally, the show segue animation (Flip Horizontal) is landscape, and ViewController B appears in landscape.

**How can I force the segue to be portrait as well and not rotate ViewController B?**

Comment: I don't think the Flip Horizontal segue works with a portrait layout. Try using a different segue.

Comment: no it works with portrait layout.  if i do not rotate the device, it looks perfect.  Also if I do not allow landscape mode via the target - it always looks fine, but I want to allow landscape on the iPad.

Comment: You can manually set the orientation when the segue appears ViewController B appears.

Comment: But the segue doesn't flip portrait... it flips landscape, which does not look right.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own custom segue? There you should be able to define which orientation to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010655

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to create a custom segue if i'm using one of Apple's prebuilt ones.  If I was trying to create a different animation completely I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests I've found that `shouldAutorotate` is only one part of the things you have to do to prevent rotation of the device. `shouldAutorotate` tells the system if it should rotate all the views as soon as someone rotates the device to a different allowed orientation.

My suggestion would be to prevent more orientations other than Landscape (which allows LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight). And by that I mean you should override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in both ViewControllers and tell the app that it should only allow landscape orientations instead of the default (which allows all but upside-down orientation).