# Custom segue without any animation

Tags: objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create custom modal segue in 4.2 Xcode using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097398/how-to-create-custom-modal-segue-in-4-2-xcode-using-storyboard)

I'm trying to implement a custom segue without any kind of animation, just the destination view controller appearing simple. How can I do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do the same as in the [How to create custom modal segue in 4.2 Xcode using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097398/how-to-create-custom-modal-segue-in-4-2-xcode-using-storyboard) question's answer, only without the Animation:

```
[src.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:NO];
```