# Programmatically push modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create custom modal segue in 4.2 Xcode using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097398/how-to-create-custom-modal-segue-in-4-2-xcode-using-storyboard)

So I have a viewController that I want to push onto my current view controller modally.  Here is the screenshot of my storyboard, with the view I'm trying to load highlighted:
[image]

So I've created a segue between the current view and the second navigation controller, lets call it "alert".  Because I don't have the segue tied to any sort of button, I'm just trying to load the view modally within the following if statement:

```
if([detector judgeSpeed:[ratio floatValue]])
{
    //push the new view here
}
```

How do I go about this?  Do I need to implement some sort of delegate or the prepareForSegue method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**presentModalViewController** is code for iOS 6 but I need code for iOS 9. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a segue, but here's another alternative:

```
SomeViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]
```

Remember to set the identifier of the view controller in your storyboard.

More information and an example project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348527/1044642).

Comment: After iOS 6, this is deprecated.  Here's an updated version of the suggested solution.

[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];

Answer (score 1):

The answer's on [How to create custom modal segue in 4.2 Xcode using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097398/how-to-create-custom-modal-segue-in-4-2-xcode-using-storyboard) should help.

[T.J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971518/t-j)'s answer:

```
UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
[UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                animations:^{
                    [src.navigationController popToViewController:[src.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];;
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

[tiguero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997084/tiguero)'s Answer:

```
[self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
```

Any of those answer's should answer this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, create a segue from the Demo Video Capture View Controller to your new view controller by ctrl-dragging from the view controller itself to the new view controller. You do this by ctrl-dragging from the yellow button in the black bar below the Demo Video Capture View Controller to the new view. When it asks which kind select `modal`. Still in storyboard, click on the segue and identify it as "alert" in the identity navigator on the right. Now go to your .m file and use this implementation...

```
if([detector judgeSpeed:[ratio floatValue]])
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"alert" sender:self];
}
```